# Javascript function output (deobfuscation)

Tags: javascript, function, deobfuscation

I have come across this code in a web page from a CTF game:

```js
function conexion() {
  var Password = "unescape(String.fromCharCode%2880%2C%20108%2C%2097%2C%20110%29):KZQWYZLOMNUWC===":

    for (i = 0; i < Password.length; i++) {
      if (Password[i].indexOf(code1) == 0) {
        var TheSplit = Password[i].split(":");
        var code1 = TheSplit[0];
        var code2 = TheSplit[1];
      }
    }
}
```

After working a little bit, I have deobfuscated the `Password` line and obtained:

```
unescape(String.fromCharCode(80, 108, 97, 110)):KZQWYZLOMNUWC===
```

which was also translated to `Password = "Plan:KZQWYZLOMNUWC===";`.

My first reading of the code is that `code1 = Plan` and `code2 = KZQWYZLOMNUWC`.

But this is not the correct answer. I’m also not sure how the `===` operates here.

May you please give me some insights?

Comment: We need to know what `code1` is initially. Currently, this code would just do nothing (if the syntax error is fixed).

Comment: Here is the context for you to understand (the code that I have posted is login.js) [link] (view-source:http://34.247.69.86/lacasadepapel/episodio1/puerta.php) [/link]

Comment: Well that function is commented, so it won’t ever do anything. The code also makes no sense. `Password` is a string, `Password[i]` would be a single character. Splitting on `:` on a single character is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. It does not make sense. It's a string, not an array. I guess it's just s decoy. I will address the game differently. Thanks for clarify my doubts!